# gem install memcached with ruby failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

that is the error message:

```
/home/alan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sasl/sasl.h... no
Please install SASL to continue. The package is called libsasl2-dev on Ubuntu and cyrus-sasl on Gentoo.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/alan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code
```

Thanks for helping me if u have spare time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It clearly states that some library is missing

```
 Please install SASL to continue. The package is called libsasl2-dev on Ubuntu and cyrus-sasl on Gentoo.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

For Ubuntu you have to install those

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

For Gentoo

install

```
cyrus-sasl
```

Comment: Looks like ubuntu package `libsasl2` was replaced by `libsasl2-2` (but `libsasl2-dev` is still good)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error logs, it says:

> Please install SASL to continue. The package is called libsasl2-dev on
>   Ubuntu and cyrus-sasl on Gentoo.

Try installing following packages before proceeding (for Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```